# Do we use the same entity class to gather information and persist data to database?

Tags: architecture, uml

My application implements digest authentication. I have been drawing Class diagrams and face a confusion. I have a Person class to gather information of authentication and I have another User class that persist the status of the authenticated user. ( I have planned to use Hibernate as ORM in future too)

Question is, do I need to use same Person class for the persisting of data or Is it OK to keep two classes for gathering information and persisting?

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user is not a person. People can exist independent of being users.

Also, a user could be an automated agent.

Often, user and person are combined into one table, but you could have a "User belongsTo a Person" relationship instead.

Somewhat related, the data structures that represent form input do not have to correspond to database entities. For example, a "change password" form would have "new password" and "confirm password" fields, however a user table would have a single password column.

Comment: I guess the Confirm Password is only temporary in the VC of the MVC. But in general I agree that Person and User should be two independent business entities.

Comment: ` the data structures that represent form input do not have to correspond to database entities.` this what I wanted to know. thanks.